# How full pass-by-name is implemented?

Tags: parameters

When you consider Scala and its pass-by-name you could (if I am not mistaken) pack the argument to lambda and pass it by value to the function. Internally the function would use pass-by-name parameter as lambda.

However in Algol you can **change** the parameter (so it is possible to write `swap` for example).

My question is -- how full pass-by-name is implemented?

Comment: [What is “pass-by-name” and how does it work exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838079/what-is-pass-by-name-and-how-does-it-work-exactly)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I already read it :-). Still I don't get it how do you substitute your local name in some external, already, compiled function? After all functions are not macros (macros like in C/C++).

Comment: `var speech = string.Format("Four-Score and {0} Years Ago", "Seven");` ... though I suspect it's not really about substituting a name in this fashion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, this is string interpolation and has nothing to do with pass-by-name mechanism. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name

Comment: What is it, *specifically,* that you don't understand?  Don't ask us to give you a primer on pass-by-name; there are already plenty of resources on the Internet that cover that subject very well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, wait a second, I am asking about pass-by-name, and you gave me example with string interpolation, and now you are angry with me, because I pointed out the reference about pass-by-name. So you do understand what it is or not? What **I** specifically don't understand is how it is implemented in Algol. You don't pass expression, you don't pass lambda, you don't pass text, so what is passed then?

Comment: Who's angry?  I'm not angry, I'm simply pointing out a plausible reason why people are closing your question. :)  I'm trying to help you out here.

Comment: Not that I know anything about Algol, but if pass by name works as described in Robert's links, I don't see how you could implement it without preserving the complete source code of every callable function at runtime so you can do textual substitution and then recompilation...at every single call site, at runtime. Which sounds totally insane, so I'm clearly missing something. And it's probably the same something the OP is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible implementations. The first is textual substitution, I.e. the called function is expanded inline with references to its parameters replaced with the code you supplies. This is basically a form of macro, and suffers from many of the problems inherent with that, most notably that a function cannot be made recursive when defined like this.

The other is to use a pair of "thunks", I.e. generated code that substitute for the operations of reading and writing the parameter. You can simulate this in an OOP language by defining an interface, e.g.

```
public interface CallByNameArg<T>
{
    void set (T value);
    T get();
}
```

Then a function uses those methods when it wants to access its arguments, e.g. a function in a call-by-name language that looks like this:

```
int sum (int index, int start, int end, int value) // call-by-name
{
    int r = 0;
    for (index = start; index < end; index ++) r += value;
    return r;
}
```

becomes

```
int sum (CallByName<int> index, CallByName<int> start, CallByName<int> end, CallByName<int> value)
{
    int r = 0;
    for (index.set (start.get ()); index.get() < end.get();
         index.set (index.get () + 1))
            r += value.get();
   return r;
}
```

and a call site:

```
int a[] = ....;
int i;
int s = sum(i, 0, a.length; a[i]);
```

becomes (assuming a language with proper closures, so not Java even though I've been using Java-like syntax):

```
int s = sum (new CallByNameArg {
    void set (int value) { i = value; }
    int get () { return i; } }, new CallByNameArg {
    void set (int value) { throw NotModifiable; }
    int get () { return 0; } } new CallByNameArg {
    void set (int value) { throw NotModifiable; }
    int get () { return a.length; } }, new CallByNameArg {
    void set (int value) { a[i] = value; }
    int get () { return a[i]; } });
```

If you don't have actual closures in your language, you can simulate them by moving modifiable variables (in this case i and a) into an object and defining the CallByNameArg instances as inner classes or similar.

Hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: That certainly makes it a lot clearer to me at least, +1. Do you know if a "real" Algol implementation is typically able to optimize away most of the function calls and closure objects created by this approach?

Comment: @lxrec, compilers developed in the 1960s didn't have much in the way of optimization, so I'm pretty sure most any implementation doesn't optimize away any of them. However, see http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/98-03-074 for some of the lower-level details. Basically, the implementation did take some shortcuts vs a proper closure implementation.

Comment: Ah, inlining! The text subsitution is very misleading, caller does not have to have access to text code of the callee, so it does not work via text substitution. Thank you very much for the answer and examples.